# Using different interface with stl datastructure

Tags: c++, stl

I want to create a class with these two constructors, but `unordered_map<void*,void*> *` and those two created in constructor is not compatible. How can I change to make the following code works while preserving the prototype of the constructors.

```
struct eq_fun
{
    bool operator()(void* s1, const void* s2) const
    {
        return ( _cmp_fn((void*)s1,(void*)s2) == 0 );
    }
    int (*_cmp_fn)(void*, void*);
    eq_fun(int (*fn)(void*, void*)):_cmp_fn(fn){}
};

struct hash_fun
{
    size_t operator()(const void *p) const
    {
        return _hash_fn(p);
    }
    int (*_hash_fn)(const void*);
    hash_fun(int (*fn)(const void*)):_hash_fn(fn){}
};

class MyClass {
    private:
        unordered_map<void*,void*> *h_map;
    public:
        template<class EQ,class HF>MyClass()
        { h_map = new unordered_map<void*,void*,HF,EQ>(); }

        MyClass(int (*h)(const void*),int (*cmp)(void*,void*))
        { h_map = new unordered_map<void*,void*,hash_fun,eq_fun>(0,hash_fun(h),eq_fun(cmp)); }
};
```

Comment: workaround for what? write a class how, specifically?

Comment: Well, this code cannot compile.

Comment: Describe, with words, what you're trying to accomplish and what problem you're running into. If you get compiler errors, quote them. It might be obvious to you, but it's impossible for someone else to guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to create a class with these two constructors, but unordered_map<void*,void*> * and those two created in constructor is not compatible. How can I change to make it works while preserving the prototype of the constructors.

Comment: Put that in the question, not buried in the comments.

Comment: and which constructors?

Comment: again, which constructors? `hash_fun` or `MyClass`?

Comment: MyClass(int (*h)(const void*),int (*cmp)(void*,void*))

Comment: Why do you use a pointer of `unordered_map`?

Comment: Because I don't know what hash and compare function is until the constructor called.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to create a different templated member depending on the template arguments of the constructor. This is impossible in C++ in two ways.

- This:

  ```
  unordered_map<void*,void*> *h_map;
  h_map = new hash_map<void*,void*,HF,EQ>();
  ```

  is invalid because `hash_map` is not a derived class of `unordered_map`.
- You cannot mix uncovertible template parameters like you're trying to do with the `EQ` and `HF` parameters. `hash_map<..,..,HF1>` and `hash_map<..,..,HF2>` are not compatible types.

The only way out that I can see is to choose either `hash_map` or `unordered_map` and make `MyClass` a template `MyClass<HF, EQ>`.

Note that when the TR1 class `hash_map` was accepted into C++11 it was renamed `unordered_map`. So they're the same thing, and it makes no sense to mix these two types in the same code. Reference: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1456.html

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I didn't intended to mix unordered_map and hash_map together. I've modified the code in the original post.

Comment: It looks like unordered_map<void*,void*> * and unordered_map<void*,void*,HF,EQ> * are compatible, but unordered_map<void*,void*> * and unordered_map<void*,void*,hash_fun,eq_fun>* are not.

Comment: That depends on what `HF` and `EQ` are.